# why can't my typo3 6.2 ajax action be found?

Tags: ajax, typo3-6.2.x

I am trying to hit an  ajax action  `"ajaxfactsAction()"` in my controller Factoids.  But when the ajax call is made I get a 303 error and a redirect to another page.

This is what I have in my template  that calls the ajax:

```
<f:section name="main">
<h1>I am</h1>
<f:form action="">
    <f:form.select id="topics" name="topics" options="{categories}" optionValueField="uid" optionLabelField="title"  additionalAttributes="{onchange: 'getFacts()'}"/>
    <f:form.hidden id="extraids" name="extraids" value="3,4,5" />
    <f:form.hidden id="number" name="number" value="3" />
</f:form>
<div>
<div class="factoid1"><f:render partial="Category/Factoid1"   /></div>
<div class="factoid2"><f:render partial="Category/Factoid2"   /></div>
<div class="factoid3"><f:render partial="Category/Factoid3"   /></div>
</div>
<f:flashMessages renderMode="div" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var actionsPathFromViewHelperSetInTheView = '<f:uri.action action="ajaxfacts" controller="Factoid" />';
</script>


</f:section>
```

and this is the javascript:

```
function performAjaxCall(Topics, Extraids, Number) {
    alert("dddd");
    $.ajax({
        url: actionsPathFromViewHelperSetInTheView,
        data:{
            "tx_factoids_interests[uid]":Topics,
            "tx_factoids_interests[extraids]":Extraids,
            "tx_factoids_interests[number]":Number
        },
        success:function (data) {
            // do something with your json
            alert('Load was performed.');
        }
    });
}

function getFacts(){
    performAjaxCall($("#topics").val(), $("#extraids").val(), $("#number").val());   
}
```

and this is my action  function:

```
/**
     * action ajaxfacts
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function ajaxfactsAction() {
        echo __LINE__;
        die;
}
```

and my plugin in ext_localconf:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Seethroughweb.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Interests',
    array(
        'Factoid' => 'interests, list, show, new, edit, create, update, ajaxfacts',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Factoid' => 'interests, list, show, new, edit, create, update, ajaxfacts',

    )
);
```

What am I missing to make the action accessible?

The resulting uri looks like this :

```
xhttp://...xyz.com/index.php?id=111&tx_factoids_interests%5Baction%5D=ajaxfacts&tx_factoids_interests%5Bcontroller%5D=Factoid&cHash=0e805af8af888ebd7fec5e207f64b5f7&tx_factoids_interests%5Buid%5D=5&tx_factoids_interests%5Bextraids%5D=3%2C4%2C5&tx_factoids_interests%5Bnumber%5D=3
```

the page is is called from is accessible with the first part ie :

```
xhttp://....xyz.com/index.php?id=111
```

I am using Typo3 6.2,
Thanks.

PS: javascript version two - made to work like the Arek's answer.

```
function performAjaxCall(Topics, Extraids, Number) {
    alert("performAjaxCall");
    $.ajax({
        url: $('form').attr('action'), // now we're using the url generated by Extbase/Fluid
        data: $('form').serialize(), // serializes the form

//        data:{
//            "tx_factoids_interests[uid]":Topics,
//          "tx_factoids_interests[extraids]":Extraids,
//          "tx_factoids_interests[number]":Number
//        },
        success:function (data) {
            // do something with your json
            alert('performAjaxCall Load was performed.');
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

PPS: the request uri from this method now looks like this:

```
http://...xyz.com/undefinedindex.php?id=111&tx_factoids_interests%5Baction%5D=ajaxfacts&tx_factoids_interests%5Bcontroller%5D=Factoid&cHash=0e805af8af888ebd7fec5e207f64b5f7
```

and current javascript:

```
function performAjaxCall( Topics, Extraids, Divid) {
    //alert("performAjaxCall");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",

        url: $('base').attr('href') + $('#form1').attr('action'), // now we're using the url generated by Extbase/Fluid
        data: $('#form1').serialize(),

//      url: actionsPathFromViewHelperSetInTheView,
//        data:{
//            "tx_factoids_interests[uid]":Topics,
//          "tx_factoids_interests[extraids]":Extraids           
//        },

        success:function (data) {
            // do something with your json

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                var items='';
                var id = '';
                $.each( val, function( ikey, ival ) {
                    if(ikey =='category') id = Divid +" #factoid"+ival; 
                    items +=  "<span class="+ikey+">" + ival + "</span><br/>" ;
                });
                $(id).html(items);

            });

//          $(".factoid1").html();
//          $(".factoid2").html();
//          $(".factoid3").html();
            //alert('performAjaxCall Load was performed.');
        }
    });
}

function getFacts(Divid){
    performAjaxCall( $(Divid+"topics").val(), $(Divid+"extraids").val(), Divid );    
    return false;
}
```

and the current template:

```
 <div id="interests">
    <f:form action="ajaxfacts" controller="Factoid" id="form1">
        <f:form.select id="intereststopics" name="topics" options="{categories}" optionValueField="uid" optionLabelField="content"  additionalAttributes="{onchange: 'getFacts(\'#interests\')'}"/>
        <f:form.hidden id="interestsextraids" name="extraids" value="2,4,5" />

    </f:form>
    <div>
    <div id="factoid2" class="factoid1"></div>
    <div id="factoid4" class="factoid2"></div>
    <div id="factoid5" class="factoid3"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

PPPS: final code

```
function performAjaxCall( Topics, Extraids, Divid, Formid) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",

        url: $(Formid).attr('action'), // now we're using the url generated by Extbase/Fluid
        data: $(Formid).serialize(),

        success:function (data) {

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                var items='';
                var id = '';
                $.each( val, function( ikey, ival ) {
                    if(ikey =='category') id = Divid +" #factoid"+ival; 
                    $(id +" ."+ikey).html(ival);

                });

            });

        }
    });
}

function getFacts(Divid, Formid){
    performAjaxCall( $(Divid+"topics").val(), $(Divid+"extraids").val(), Divid, Formid );    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It may be some cHash error. Disable the `[FE][pageNotFoundOnCHashError]` option from the install tool, `clear all caches` and try again.

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked.  Is there a bug in typo3 or did I do something to cause that?  Not sure if I'll  need to enable that option again. Add that as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Answered. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the `<f:form action="">`.

The calculated `cHash` is in your case based on the URL generated by `<f:uri>` which does not contain any information about the other properties you added in your JavaScript. Hereby you're running into the `cHash` error.

You can prevent that the `pageNotFoundHandler` is called on a `cHash` error by disabling `$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['pageNotFoundOnCHashError']` (Local Configuration).

For more information abount the `cHash`:

> [The mysteries of &cHash](https://typo3.org/documentation/article/the-mysteries-of-chash-1/)
>
> The &cHash parameter of frontend plugins might have puzzled quite a few developers but this article will explain how it works and what to avoid in order to make great, reliable plugins with TYPO3.

**Solution**

Instead of making a custom `url` you need to use the `action` from the form generated by Extbase/Fluid.

So your form should look like:

```
<f:form action="ajaxfacts" controller="Factoid">
```

And your JavaScript should look like:

```
$(function() { 

    $('form').submit(function(e) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('base').attr('href') + $('form').attr('action'), // now we're using the url generated by Extbase/Fluid
            data: $('form').serialize(), // serializes the form
            success:function (data) {
                // do something with your json
                alert('Load was performed.');
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

});
```

PPPS Final js code:

```
function performAjaxCall( Topics, Extraids, Divid, Formid) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", 
        dataType: "json",


        url: $(Formid).attr('action'), // now we're using the url generated by Extbase/Fluid
        data: $(Formid).serialize(),

        success:function (data) {

            $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
                var items='';
                var id = '';
                $.each( val, function( ikey, ival ) {
                    if(ikey =='category') id = Divid +" #factoid"+ival; 
                    $(id +" ."+ikey).html(ival);
                    //items +=  "<span class="+ikey+">" + ival + "</span><br/>" ;
                });

            });

        }
    });
}

function getFacts(Divid, Formid){
    performAjaxCall( $(Divid+"topics").val(), $(Divid+"extraids").val(), Divid, Formid );    
    return false;
}
```

Comment: interesting, but now I get a 404 error on the ajax call.  see my update to show how I changed the javascript - I 'm not sure why you did your js that way - mine needs to fire on the change event.

Comment: Do you have the requested uri for me?

Comment: Try to POST it, instead of GET. I did add it to my answer (look at the js example)

Comment: And also added the baseUrl. If it still does not work then please add here the new url #gonnafixthisthing :)

Comment: Thanks Arek, same problem though, new url is  http://...xyz.com/undefinedgeneral/search/index.htm,  the form variables look right though: q:
tx_factoids_interests[__referrer][@extension]:Factoids
tx_factoids_interests[__referrer][@vendor]:Seethroughweb
tx_factoids_interests[__referrer][@controller]:Factoid
tx_factoids_interests[__referrer][@action]:interests
tx_factoids_interests[__referrer][arguments]:YT..3b
tx_factoids_interests[__trustedProperties]:a:2:{s:6:"topics";i:1;s:8:"extraids";i:1;}caf717...49
tx_factoids_interests[topics]:9
tx_factoids_interests[extraids]:2,4,5

Comment: The `action` attribute on the generated `form` tag does not contain the `Controller` and `Action`. Can you double check if you provided the `<f:form action="ajaxfacts" controller="Factoid">`?

Comment: If you do then something else is pbb being a problem right now (like realurl, caching etcetera). So unload realurl (or truncate all realurl related tables except _redirects`, trigger the `clear all caches` button in the install tool and try again..

Comment: updated question with new uri, I guess I had forgotten last time to give the form a proper id - needed since there will be two forms on the same page.  I will also show my full javascript as it is now.

Comment: `data: $('form').serialize(),` should be `data: $('#form1').serialize(),`

Comment: true, sorry about that, but even fixed the uri becomes:  (note undefined) http://...xyz.com/undefinedindex.php?id=111&tx_factoids_interests%5Baction%5D=ajaxfacts&tx_factoids_interests%5Bcontroller%5D=Factoid&cHash=0e805af8af888ebd7fec5e207f64b5f7